# Way to use an ArrayList without ConcurrentModificationException(s)?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, arraylist

**JAVA**

I have an ArrayList in my game to store all the particles ingame. I have an update method which accesses the ArrayList to update the physics, I have a render method that accesses the ArrayList to render the particles onscreen and a MouseClick listener that when it detects a MouseClick it will add a new Particle to the ArrayList.

My problem is I keep getting an java.util.ConcurrentModificationException. This is because when I click at the same time it renders and both methods are trying to access the ArrayList. Is there a solution to accessing the ArrayList at the same time (different data type?).

Some code to help out-

**ArrayList Declaration**

```
ArrayList<Particle> ParticleList = new ArrayList<Particle>();
```

**Particle Class Definition**

```
public class Particle {

int x;
int y;
Color colour;
int type;
//0:wall
public Particle(int x,int y,Color colour,int type)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.colour = colour;
    this.type = type;
}`
```

**Render Method**

```
for(Particle e : this.ParticleList)
{
g.fillRect(e.x, e.y, 1, 1);
}
```

Comment: If you try to add/remove during an iteration 2 things: use ListIterator.remove/add but besides adding/removing at the end it could be slow. Most likely you may need to redesign the data structure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: It seems you are not having multithreaded access, so my original answer doesn't hold (I'll keep it for the sake of completeness)

`ConcurrentModificationException` in a single thread occurs only if you are adding or removing from a collection while it is being iterated. To fix that, create a new collection that's a copy of the first one, and add to it instead.

---

If your writes (clicks) are way less than the number of reads, then you can use 
`CopyOnWriteArrayList`

Otherwise you would have to synchronize when iterating. Or get a copy (`List copy = new ArrayList(original)`)

Comment: the problem described is not a result of a multi-threaded manupulation, CoWArrayList has O(n*n) even for adding so, particles looks a lot and will be utterly slow. Since the issue doesn't seem multi-threaded sync will not do the trick.

Comment: @bestsss I didn't quite get the problem described, that's why I have an "if" and "otherwise". adding to COWAL is the slowest operation indeed, that's why if should be used only if a few additions are there. Also, I'm still under the impression that there is a multithreaded access. It looks like swing with event thread and main thread.

Comment: @Bozho, he would not have been able to describe it w/ click and so on, one common issue w/ multithreaded issues are they are hard to reproduce/describe.

Comment: @Liam E-p then show the code.. if it's not multithreaded, I believe the issue is rather simple.

Comment: @Liam E-p I don't see any list iteration there. Where does the exception occur?

Comment: @Boho Sorry I didn't post the code for ParticleManager.java where the exception is occuring http://pastebin.com/gKvyw46S

Answer (score 2):

Swing itself is implicitly single threaded.  Your clicks and your rendering should be on the same thread.  If you do this you won't get a ConcurrentModificationException because you will only be rendering or processing clicks.